# How to remove ./a.out when displaying input on command line into arrays?

Tags: c++, linux, argv

[My program needs to accept input from the linux command line and organize it into arrays. a[0] is supposed to show the first integer input by the user. However I get a[0] = ./a.out. How would I remove ./a.out and have a[0] = the first integer?]

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 using namespace std;

 int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
 {    
         for(int i = 0; i < argc;++i)
         {

                 printf("\nargv[%d]: %s\n",i,argv[i]);
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Start at index 1, but display as if it were index 0.

```c
for(int i = 1; i < argc;++i)
{
    printf("\nargv[%d]: %s\n", i-1, argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I needed to minus by one but I was a little confused on where. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an `std::vector<std::string>` containing the command line arguments from `argv` by simply skipping the first element (i.e., the program name):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

auto main(int argc, char *argv[]) -> int {
   // skip the program name by starting at offset 1 instead of 0
   std::vector<std::string> args(argv + 1, argv + argc);

   for (auto const& arg: args)
      std::cout << arg << '\n';
}
```

This way, `args[0]` will correspond to the first argument that was provided to the program at the command line. Assuming the program is called `a.out`, running it as:

```
./a.out 1 2 3
```

results in the output:

```
1
2
3
```

The program name, i.e., `./a.out`, was skipped when creating the `args` vector, so it only contains the arguments passed at the command line, i.e., `1`, `2` and `3`.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep this in mind for future work with vectors :)